# Compare current time with time in textbox

Tags: vb.net, forms, time, timer, basic

How can i compare my current time with the time i have in format example "07:00"

I want to check current time and if is current time in interval 07:00 - 07:45 to show me message in textbox .

My current work

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim curtime As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        tmrNow.Enabled = True
        If curtime < "07:00" And curtime > "07:45" Then
            lblPeriod.Text = "Time is in range "
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrNow_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrNow.Tick
        txtNow.Text = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm")
        curtime = txtNow.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you are not comparing times/dates, you are comparing strings (`Dim curtime As String`).  declare curtime as DateTime and set it directly in the Tick event rather that hopscotching thru a textbox and converting to string.  Also, Form Load only happens once, so the check will happen before the Timer ever goes off

Comment: @Plutonix You mean't something like this
[link]http://pokit.org/get/?d1dc08f3889d9c0e51cd88b898f11921.jpg . Am I doing it wrong by converting the time to string and than compare ? I fixed the curtime variable from string to datetime. How ti fix this tostring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` is an actual Type in .NET specifically for evaluating times and dates.  Also, you are setting `lblPeriod` in Form load which only happens once, and probably before the Timer ever goes off to set the current date time variable.

```
Private curDT as DateTime

Private Sub tmrNow_Tick(....
    curDt = DateTime.Now
    txtNow.Text = curDt.ToString("hh:mm")

    ' evaluate the time:
    If curDt.Hour = 7 AndAlso (curDt.Minute >= 0 And curDt.Minute <= 45) Then
          lblPeriod.Text = "Time is in range "
    End If

End Sub
```

`Strings` are a different Type and not meant for doing math or `DateTime` comparisons.  Code such as this:

```
 If curtime < "07:00" And curtime > "07:45" Then
```

will fail because `"07:00"` is not a time value - it is text (string) which is merely in time format.  Your *brain* interprets it as a time because of the pattern, but to the computer it has no more significance than "Ziggy" or "Apple".  That is why we use a `DateTime` variable and the properties it provides to check/text the time (hours, minutes, seconds etc) or date (month, day, year).

Similarly, `ToString("hh:mm")` converts our `DateTime` variable to a string in a pattern so the user's brain (hopefully) can interpret what is going on.

Comment: Wow so originally explained. @Plutonix thank you very much . After few weeks trying to realize the DateTime function i manage to realize it now. Have a nice day

Comment: Just one thing more how can i check the time interval ex 7:45 and 8:30 . Thanks a lot

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean by interval, that might involve a `TimeSpan` depending on the context and usage.  if you just want to  change the 7:00 to 7:45 range above, just change the evaluation.

Comment: I know i shouldn't use operator "And" so much like this.

I want to check if the time is in range from 7:45 to 8:30 to write in label "2nd Period"

  ElseIf curDT.Hour >= 7 And curDT.Minute >= 45 And curDT.Hour <= 8 And curDT.Minute <= 30 Then
            lblPeriod.Text = "2 nd Period "

Comment: From 7hours 45min's   TO   8hours 30minute's In label should stay message "Period two"

Check this photo 
http://pokit.org/get/?d4b6cdffb01f6f6fba1749bf1a557a02.jpg

Comment: that new expression needs work.  `>=45` is in both of them and 7;45 cant be in both ranges.  Also, both Hour tests should be hour = 8 and hour=7 for the second one; you only want And not AndAlso in the new test too.

Comment: I understand the first part of your post about >=45 and i fixed in first case i set >=45 and in other case i set <45 so i think it's not problem there anymore. Also about the 2nd part of your post where u said about the hours "hour = 8 and hour=7" i didn't quite understand it. Can you show me on example how ? So i can mark this question resolved

Comment: hour > 45 for the second...you need something like this: `ElseIf (curDt.Hour = 7 And curDt.Minute > 45) Or (curDt.Hour = 8 And curDt.Minute = 0) Then...`  for the second range the hour must *be* 7  or 8...if it is 8 then the mins must *be* 0.